# How to determine why sigterm was sent to process running inside docker container on mesos?

Tags: debugging, docker, mesos, alpine-linux, sigterm

I have a docker container that I can excecute fine locally. Yet when run on a mesos cluster, I get SIGTERMS

```
/usr/my_script.sh: line 57:   310 Killed xsltproc sort.xsl ${2} > ${2}_bat
W0703 09:09:54.465442  5074 logging.cpp:91] RAW: Received signal SIGTERM from process 2262 of user 0; exiting
```

I don't understand where this problem is comming from and how to best debug it. How can I find out what's killing my container?

I tried increasing the RAM of the container available to over 4GB, yet to no avail. Furthermore, according to `/usr/bin/time -v xsltproc sort.xsl offending_file.xml > sortedFile.xml` the process should only consume 1GB RAM.

I also tried googling for the error output of `W0703` and `5074 logging.cpp:91`, yet to no avail. It also begs the question why the container has no problem executing the command when run locally.

Comment: How much memory is available on the host? Can you check the host `dmesg` output to see if the OOM killer might have killed it? The `Killed` in the log output is suspect of the OOM killer.

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/858982/who-is-killing-my-docker-container). Can you post more details? Logs from mesos-agent and executor. Are you usinge Mesos Healthchecks?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue.  I was running a docker container on Chronos and left the `"command"` field blank, assuming it would execute `CMD` in the Dockerfile when not overridden.  Explicitly copying the command into the Mesos configuration fixed the issue for me.